# Any way to check if a XmlSchemaParticle is an EmptyParticle?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm struggling with something here, is there a *proper* way to check whether a `XmlSchemaParticle` is an `EmptyParticle` or not?

`XmlSchemaParticle.EmptyParticle` seems to be a private inner class of `XmlSchemaParticle`.

What I'm doing right now is `particle.GetType().Name == "EmptyParticle"` and I find it rather ugly.

Any other option?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem today. I was able to get around it by checking [XmlSchemaComplexType.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype.contenttype%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) property:

```
public bool HasEmptyParticle(XmlSchemaComplexType type)
{
    return type.ContentTypeParticle != null && type.ContentType == XmlSchemaContentType.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I think you're answer is correct...ish, because it's not complete - an empty particle is also returned for `XmlSchemaContentType.TextOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried the same solution as you, but it's messy alright. Just about to try: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/54685/detecting-xmlschemacomplextype-contentparticletype-is-equal.aspx

Comment: I am debugging an instance of empty particle and the complex type content model is null, so the assertion from that thread post was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should consider any [ContentTypeParticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacomplextype.contenttypeparticle.aspx) with `MaxOccurs == 0` to be empty.

Comment: Well then I don't understand the purpose of that `EmptyParticle` class.

Comment: `EmptyParticle` being non-public clearly means it's not for external usage. Whatever they do (or don't do) with it internally isn't meant to be know by the users of `XmlSchemaParticle`.

Comment: They shouldn't be returning something of that type then, don't you think ?

Comment: Well, from an architectural point of view, they don't. It is just that they use that class for some internal reason which is not reflected through the API. Users of the API should not be concerned with the exact implementation of XmlSchemaParticle but instead act upon the public properties that it expose.

Comment: By the way your answer is not correct, I get plenty of `EmptyParticle` with `MaxOccurs > 0`.

Comment: Ok. I might be completely wrong. And I see that my answer is incomplete. I was referring to the ContentTypeParticle property of XmlSchemaComplexType. Sorry that I can't help you out.

Comment: No problem. I actually use the `ContentTypeParticle`. I agree that a `ContentTypeParticle` with `MaxOccurs == 0` would be empty, but that doesn't imply that any empty `ContentTypeParticle` (i.e `EmptyParticle`) has `MaxOccurs == 0`, because I get a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but what if you checked if the ContentTypeParticle was not public.

If (!type.ContentTypeParticle.GetType().IsPublic)
{

}

I know you're specifically testing for empty, but could we go under the assumption that an internal/private object type reflects empty?

Comment: This is way dirtier than `particle.GetType().Name == "EmptyParticle"` – Also it could be (and most certainly is) plain wrong. Nothing tells me that `EmptyParticle` is the only private particle type.

Comment: That's true.  Just trying to avoid testing against the name of an internal class, which theoretically could change.  Not exactly clean either.